# MGTwitter: libxml/xmlreader.h file not found in XCode 4.5

Tags: twitter, libxml2, xcode4.5

I just downloaded Xcode 4.5 and I cant seem to run my application as the MGTwitter... classes are complaining of a non inclusion error of LibXML2. I have imported it into the frameworks folder, and I have put the following in the header bit in the build settings

$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

```
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h> file not found
```

My app compiles with no issues using Xcode 4.3, but when I try to compile using 4.5 I get this error

I tried this also:
 $(SDK_DIR)/usr/include/libxml2

Is this just a bug or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: single quote instead of forward slash in first path.  Is that your config setting or the output?

Comment: Try: /Applications/Xcode.app$ find . -name xmlreader.h

Comment: My XCode 4.5 has it under ./Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h

Comment: I have just edited my question

Comment: single quote was just written in the question by mistake

Comment: confirm which SDK you're building with in both XCode 4.3 & 4.5 - then use the find command above under both XCodes and both SDKs to see what's different ...

Comment: I am using sdk iOS 5.0 for Xcode 4.3 and sdk iOS 6.0 for Xcode 4.5

Comment: but didn't get your find command suggestion

Comment: I'm not sure how to check which SDK I'm using, so I checked all SDK folders and every SDK has `xmlreader.h` at the same path. It is absolutely NO DIFFERENCE in this file location inside the Xcode 4.3 and Xcode 4.5 packages. But Xcode 4.3 compiles project, but Xcode 4.5 failed with linker error.

Comment: I FOUND SOMETHING! When I type `$(SDK_DIR)` in `Header search path` in Xcode 4.5 it converted to value `/Applications/XCode 4.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0sdk`, but this path does NOT exist! Under `iPhoneOS.platform` the only SDK is `iPhoneOS5.1.sdk`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
/usr/include/libxml2
```

in header search paths. Just it, **without** `$(SDKROOT)` or `$(SDK_DIR)`.

Comment: what worked for me was: "$(SDK_DIR)/usr/include/libxml2" recursive and including the double quotes.... I added this to Header search path under the TARGET.

Comment: @Mike Keskinov, Cool. It worked for me as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a good solution as it will not use the correct headers for whatever SDK you are building with and may result in different behavior on different computers.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to fix the problem in one of my projects by adding double quotes around the path. Because I put Xcode 4.5 in a path with a space in it things broke.  So I changed 
$(SDK_DIR)/usr/include/libxml2
to 
"$(SDK_DIR)/usr/include/libxml2"

Comment: Double quotes. Good Call.

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue some days ago, and i follow below steps:

- You just need to add libxml2.dylib framework.
- and add **/usr/include/libxml2** in Header Search path.

It worked for me.